# Counting printed Pages by Clients with c# and WMI

Tags: c#, printing, wmi

the goal is like i said in the Topic. I know there are a lot of articles on that specific Problem and i tried all most all of them.
But since non of them worked out for me, I'm now trying to find out why this one just works **sometimes** and sometimes nothing is happening although many things are printed.
So this is my code which right now should wait for a job to be printed and just tell me about it. Nothing more.

```
private void StartMonitor()
    {

        try
        {
            var opt = new ConnectionOptions { EnablePrivileges = true };

            var scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2", opt);

            scope.Connect();

            var query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \"Win32_PrintJob\"");

            var watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);

            Console.WriteLine("Ready to receive Printer Job events...");

            var pjEvent = watcher.WaitForNextEvent();

            if (pjEvent != null) Console.WriteLine("Event occured: " + pjEvent.Properties["PagesPrinted"]);
        }
        catch (ManagementException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            Console.WriteLine(e.ErrorCode);
            Console.WriteLine(e.ErrorInformation);
            _Error = e.Message;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the progress of the printed pages for a particular job, try using a smaller polling interval  and use the [`EventArrivedEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.eventarrivedeventhandler.aspx) delegate attached to the WMI event for handling the incoming data in a asynchronous way.

Try this sample.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;


namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    public class EventWatcherAsync 
    {
        private void WmiEventHandler(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TargetInstance.Caption :         " + ((ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value)["Caption"]);
            Console.WriteLine("TargetInstance.JobStatus :       " + ((ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value)["JobStatus"]);
            Console.WriteLine("TargetInstance.PagesPrinted :    " + ((ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value)["PagesPrinted"]);
            Console.WriteLine("TargetInstance.Status :          " + ((ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value)["Status"]);

        }

        public EventWatcherAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                string ComputerName = "localhost";
                string WmiQuery;
                ManagementEventWatcher Watcher;
                ManagementScope Scope;   


                if (!ComputerName.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
                {
                    ConnectionOptions Conn = new ConnectionOptions();
                    Conn.Username  = "";
                    Conn.Password  = "";
                    Conn.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";
                    Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), Conn);
                }
                else
                    Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);
                Scope.Connect();

                WmiQuery ="Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent Within 1 "+
                "Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PrintJob' ";

                Watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(Scope, new EventQuery(WmiQuery));
                Watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(this.WmiEventHandler);
                Watcher.Start();
                Console.Read();
                Watcher.Stop();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception {0} Trace {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
            }

        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Listening {0}", "__InstanceOperationEvent");
           Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
           EventWatcherAsync eventWatcher = new EventWatcherAsync();
           Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Helpful but, In remote network clients when shared network printer select for print, "TotalPages" are zero, why?

Answer (score 2):

To get the total pages printed by a job I would try monitoring __InstanceDeletionEvents, I believe that at that time Win32_PrintJob.TotalPages should  show the printed pages accurately (can't test this right now, sorry). There is also a nice alternative here:

[Monitoring a Printer Queue from VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3313/Monitoring-a-Printer-Queue-from-VB-NET)

If you look at the article comments, the author also advises to monitor JOB_WRITTEN events to get the total number of pages printed.

If you are trying to monitor the progress of large print jobs, try monitoring __InstanceModificationEvents once the job is created, something like this:

```
Select * From __InstanceModificationEvent Within 1 
Where TargetInstance Isa "Win32_PrintJob" 
And TargetInstance.PagesPrinted > PreviousInstance.PagesPrinted
```

Comment: But in network printers, TotalPages is always zero! why?