# Pause print job immediately in C#

Tags: c#

I find this way to starting an EventWatcher: [Counting printed Pages by Clients with c# and WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934063/counting-printed-pages-by-clients-with-c-sharp-and-wmi)

I need to pause every print when job incoming and I add this code at "WmiEventHandler":

```
        string searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob";
        ManagementObjectSearcher searchPrintJobs = new ManagementObjectSearcher(searchQuery);
        ManagementObjectCollection prntJobCollection = searchPrintJobs.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject prntJob in prntJobCollection) {
            String jobName = prntJob.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
            //Job name would be of the format [Printer name], [Job ID]
            char[] splitArr = new char[1];
            splitArr[0] = Convert.ToChar(",");
            string prnterName = jobName.Split(splitArr)[0];
            int prntJobID = Convert.ToInt32(jobName.Split(splitArr)[1]);
            string documentName = prntJob.Properties["Document"].Value.ToString();
            prntJob.InvokeMethod("Pause", null);

        }
```

But this way is too slow to pause the job, I want to find a way to pause current print job when ManagementEventWatcher watch.